# Не работает панель задач windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-11

Проблем заключается в том, что я не могу перейти с открытого на весь экран окна в другое которое открыто не на весь экран. Когда нажимаю на иконку приложения на панели задач то оно открывается, но как только я начинаю вести к открытому окну мышку, когда мышка выходит из области панели задач, оно закрывается. То есть когда указатель мышки выходит за пределы панели задач оно оказывается на текущем окне которое открыто на весь экран.

Answer (score 0):

Для переключения между окнами попробуйте комбинацию клавиш <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: Сейчас я и так делаю, но все таки мне было бы удобно переключаться кликами мышки